# Why is Jeor Mormont on the Wall?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

We have seen Jeor Mormont on the Wall from season 1. He was Lord Commander on the Wall and he is from the Mormont family. We don't know if he has done anything wrong.

Some people like Benjen Stark, mostly youngest sons in the North, go to the Wall as they cannot be the Lord of their house. However, that was not the case with Jeor as his son succeeded him.

So, why is he on the Wall?

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to http://scifi.stackexchange.com/ ? It seems like a better fit there.

Comment: @einpoklum why is that? The question specifically refers to a season of a tv show. There's definitely overlap, but this is on topic in both places.

Comment: @kuhl: Because answers typically use knowledge from the books.

Comment: @einpoklum but that is case with most of Game of Thrones and Harry porter questions. Even lot of MCU answers comes from comics

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Source [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/24m8bt/spoilers_all_why_was_jeor_mormont_sent_to_the_wall/) :

> People are going to say that he took the black so his son could rule because that has sprouted up on the wiki and been taken for fact despite that there is nothing to even indicate that in the books.
>
> > I married young, to a bride of my father’s choosing, a Glover of Deepwood Motte. Ten years we were wed, or near enough as makes no matter. She was a plain-faced woman, but not unkind. I suppose I came to love her after a fashion, though our relations were dutiful rather than passionate. Three times she miscarried while trying to give me an heir. The last time she never recovered. She died not long after.”
> >
> > Dany put her hand on his and gave his fingers a squeeze. “I am sorry for you, truly.”
> >
> > Ser Jorah nodded. “By then my father had taken the black, so I was Lord of Bear Island in my own right. I had no lack of marriage offers, but before I could reach a decision Lord Balon Greyjoy rose in rebellion against the Usurper, and Ned Stark called his banners to help his friend Robert.

This is an excerpt from ["Daenerys I", chapter 12 in *A Clash of Kings*](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Clash_of_Kings-Chapter_12).

**That's the closest we have to an explanation of his taking the black which as you can see is no explanation at all.**

Answer (score 23):

Neither the show or the books really get into Jeor Mormont's reasonings for being at the Night's Watch. As one of the older generation, in the book's history instead of the present day events that the series covers, and as mostly a bit character, Jeor is not given much attention. As other's have mention, Jeor **abdicated** his seat as Lord of Bear Island and head of House Mormont. He voluntarily goes to the Wall, so his son took over.

---

**It's really so his family and land can prosper. Given a bit of background, we can guess why.**

First, Bear Island and House Mormont, while noted as a reputable house, a bannerman of Winterfell, it was not particularly prosperous. Small, poor, not much land, a modest castle.

Second, Jeor is old. Jorah is not.

Third, he gives up his place roughly right before, or during the rebellion against the old Mad King by Robert Baratheon.

Fourth, aside from Jorah, there is no male to take over.

Fifth, if someone is *requested* to become Kingsguard, they take a vow against owning land or marrying.

Combining these facts, you can make an assumption that Jeor did it to ensure that House Mormont is well taken care of, and the Bear Islands are kept in the House Mormont's name. Also, that had he not joined the Night's Watch, it would have had to be him, as Ned Stark's bannerman, to fight in the rebellion. With Jorah as head of the house, he would be the bannerman, and he could not be obligated to join the Kingsguard, a possible outcome. He would also be a better fighter than Jeor, and any accolades Jorah would receive would be good for House Mormont. It was a calculated move, by a wise man, who knows the politics of Westeros well. Remember, Westeros culture heavily favors family over individuals, and the land over the family.

Of course, Jorah goes and ruins it by selling slaves against the law, because his wife likes fancy things, but hey, kids, what can you do, right?

Comment: Do you have a source for the high likelihood of Jorah joining the kingsguard? Just curious, can't remember anything from the books or show touching on this.

Comment: @tobbe nothing to say it's a high likelyhood, just possible, as a good fighter and all.

Comment: One critique of this premise. If Jorah goes south with Ned and dies, there is no male heir and Jeor is out of the picture. Jeor can not come back, so I'm not sure that the preservation of the line really works. Also, I don't remember any reference for Jorah really being that amazing of a swordsman. Can you please back that up as the kingsguard reason is based on that?

Comment: @kuhl its all politics. Look at how Harrenhal gets passed around. Look at how Tyrel was going to name Loras to kings guard to get his way. As for him being a good swordsman, look  at his performance as Stormborn's guard.

Comment: The Jeor in the book seemed to be content on the wall, and seemed not to care so much about his family name (at least as the Lord Commander). I think a recall a quote by Jon (?) lamenting about how Mormont had a full life before joining the Watch and wishing he had had the same.

Comment: @cde but your politics don't make sense. Bear Island isn't a powerful region, Robert might not even be aware of the Mormonts. The examples of a political posting to the kingsguard are Jaime Lannister (son and heir to one of the 4 most powerful lords in the land) and Loras Tyrell  (in the show the son and heir to the guy with the largest army and brother of the queen).  The Mormonts are minor vassals to Winterfell, not a major house.

Answer (score -1):

From memory, he went in place of his son Jorah, who was charged with essentially slave trading/people smuggling but bailed to Essos.

Comment: When did this happen? In book? show?

Comment: Turns out my memory on this was off. I'll delete this.